# getText() of an element outside any tag without using text() in xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, invalidselectorexception

So I need to get a particular text in a webpage that contains 200+ lines of text outside a tag or after span tag.

I was able to get the exact xpath,

```
By outputVersion = By.xpath("//*[@class='output']/text()[contains(.,'TEXT THAT I NEED')]");
```

```
By outputVersion = By.xpath("//*[@class='timestamp']/following-sibling::text()[contains(.,'TEXT THAT I NEED')]");
```

Although it has `text()` on the xpath that I have came up with and using this, I'm having `org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException` whenever I use getText(), getAttribute("value") and getAttribute("innerText").

The actual page elements looks likes this

```
<pre class="output">
    <span class="timestamp">time</span>
    "TEXT"

    <span class="timestamp">time</span>
    "TEXT"
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <span class="timestamp">time</span>
    "TEXT THAT I NEED"  
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
</pre>
```

With that, I need to come up with an xpath excluding text() on it.

Please note that the `<span class="timestamp">time</span>` are more than 200+ lines with different texts and are changing from time to time. Also the text that I need is not in a fixed line location so I'm dependent to the `contains`

Comment: This depends on the hosting language XPath API. Is there any method for handling  text nodes results?

Comment: @Alejandro, there is an alternative to locate an element using text node. please refer my answer

Comment: The issue is about WebDriver specification see https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/340

Comment: @Miel Yan, Does any answer resolve you issue ? If yes then please accept the answer by click on tick mark below the vote count on answer. So it can be helpful for others. If no then update your question with more details or feel free to ask in comments. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method to get only parent text.

**Java implementation:**

```
public String get_text_from_parent_by_postion(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, int textPosition) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    return (String) js.executeScript("var parent = arguments[0];var textPosition = arguments[1]; var txtPosition = 0; var child = parent.firstChild; var textValue=''; while(child) { if (child.nodeType === 3){ if (txtPosition===(textPosition-1)){ textValue = child.textContent; break;}}else{txtPosition+=1;}child = child.nextSibling; } return textValue;", element, textPosition);
}
```

This is how to call this method in your case  -

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='output']"));
get_text_from_parent_by_postion(driver, element,3)
```

**python implementation:**

```
        def get_text_from_parent_by_postion(element, textPosition=1):
    return driver.execute_script(
        """ var parent = arguments[0];
            var textPosition = arguments[1];
            var txtPosition = 0;
            var child = parent.firstChild;
            var textValue="";
            while(child) {
              if (child.nodeType === 3){                        
                if (txtPosition===(textPosition-1)){
                  textValue = child.textContent;                
                  break;
                }}else{txtPosition+=1;}
              child = child.nextSibling;
            }
        return textValue;""",
        element, textPosition).strip()
```

Comment: I need this in java. :(

Comment: Check the updated answer with the java method, let me know how it goes.

Comment: ```Thrown Exception : invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@class='output']/text()[contains(.,'TEXT THAT I NEED')]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element. (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)```

Comment: check the updated answer. My bad, I have provided the another method which should get all the direct text of the pare node.

Comment: Selenium `findElement` will return element but the xpath you provided in the above comment will return the test, so you are getting that message. Try the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191336/discussion-between-supputuri-and-miel-yan).

Comment: It is still the same. Returns an invalid selector exception.

Comment: As I've stated above, I need to come up with an xpath excluding text() on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
"return document.evaluate(\"//*[@class='timestamp']/following-sibling::text()[contains(.,'TEXT THAT I NEED')]\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null);"
```

You can use your Xpath, try to pass it to the JavascriptExecutor, It will be like:

```
public String yourMethodName(WebDriver webDriver, String yourText) {
        String script = String.format("return document.evaluate(\"//*[@class='timestamp']/following-sibling::text()[contains(.,'%s')]\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null);", yourText);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
        return (String) js.executeScript(script);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate the xpath using javascript execution refer below code :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Object textYouWant= js.executeScript("var value = document.evaluate(\"//*[@class='timestamp']/following-sibling::text()[contains(.,'TEXT THAT I NEED')]\",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ); return value.stringValue;");
System.out.println(textYouWant.toString().trim());
```

For more details regarding `evaluate()` refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)